# Updating Google Sheet Cells from a Gsheet template using scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to return some values from one Google Sheet to another using a script.

I am trying to build a Google Sheet briefing document template for our marketing team so they can fill out their requirements and at the click of a button this would trigger several scripts to:

1. send an email to a specific team member
2. import data into another spreadsheet

The idea is to create a master campaign calendar spreadsheet for our Email Campaign Manager that will be automatically updated when other team members filled out the template sheet.

I have managed to do the first task using the following code:

```
*function sendemail() {
  MailApp.sendEmail("email@company.com.au,","a new EDM brief has been posted in Google Sheet","Hello, a new brief has been posted - Google Sheet URL );
}*
```

I would like the second task to get done by triggering a script at the same time (fired when users click a button in the brief doc)

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I am stuck here. I am new to Google Apps Script and I do not know which one can achieve what I am looking for.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot
currently:

`function myFunction() {
MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "xx@xx.com.au",
     subject: "xx",
  htmlBody: " xxx",
}

function Copy() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxx');
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('xxx');
 var range = ss.getRange('xx');
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxx'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('xxx'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
}`

I am currently going with this but I cannot even save it. And I dont know if I can use two functions in one script